# socket with thread closing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sockets

I'm creating a client/server application managed by Sockets and Thread.
I want to know how to close properly the socket and the related threads.
This is my code:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    try
    {
        if (UserList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (User user in UserList)
            {
                Socket socketUser = user.getSocket();
                socketUser.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("!close"));
                socketUser.Close();
            }
        }
        thrAccept.Abort();
        thrReceive.Abort();
        socket.Close();
        incoming.Close();

        Application.Exit();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("aasa");
    }
}

private void connectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string port=portNum.Text;
    string welcome = "Server up and running - " + System.DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats()[0] + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") + "\n" + "Listening Port: " + port + "\n";
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(portNum.Text)));
    socket.Listen(3);

    thrAccept = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Accept));
    serverLog.AppendText(welcome + "\n");
    thrAccept.Start();
    connectBtn.Enabled = false;
}

private void Accept()
{
    while (true)
    {
        incoming = socket.Accept();
        thrReceive = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receive));
        thrReceive.Start();
    }
}

private void Receive()
{
    User user = new User();//create an istance for the class User

    while (true)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
        incoming.Receive(buffer);
        // the program continue....
```

How can I close correctly the socket?

Class User

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace HW2_SERVER
{
    class User
    {
        public string username;
        public Socket S;
        public string role;
        public bool managed;
        public User()
        {
            username = "";
            S = null;
            role = "";
            managed = false;

        }

        public void setManage(bool i)
        {
            managed = i;
        }
        public void setUsername(string u)
        {
            username = u;
        }
        public void setSocket(Socket sock)
        {
            S = sock;
        }
        public void setRole(string r)
        {
            role = r;
        }
        public bool getManaged()
        {
            return managed;
        }
        public string getUsername()
        {
            return username;

        }
        public Socket getSocket()
        {
            return S;
        }
        public string getRole()
        {
            return role;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you thought about calling socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both); before calling socket.Close?

Comment: I try your hint but also like this I riceve the exception (in this case the messagebox)

Comment: look at the example where you are calling socket.Close, you should also put that in the foreach loop and remove the socket.Close(); call outside of the foreach loop

Comment: you may also want to put the code in this event or at least check for it then close it in this Event `OnSocketConnected`

Comment: yes what u said is right, but actually i'm trying to close the socket without clients connected, so that if will be executed only in case there's at least 1 user connected to the server, so now i don't need to use socket.close() in that loop

Comment: then you need to add an else { } if I am understanding you correctly

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overwriting your reference to `socket` and `incoming`. I assume these are fields on the class. I think you need to keep a collection of these objects, and close all of them when you're shutting down.

Also, aborting threads is a bad idea as you don't know what operation the thread was doing at the time it was being aborted. It's considered a better practice to make a graceful shutdown by setting a flag and checking it in the loop. This may be the cause of your exception. I suggest you don't abort the threads, and instead find a proper way to shut everything down. You're more likely to find a bug-free path this way.

I would replace both of your `while (true)` loops with `while (_isRunning)`. Set that as a field on the class with a public value. When you're closing down, set it to false and the threads will exit gracefully.

Comment: can u give me a real example, I'm not very skilled in C#, and I have to do this software for an homework. Thank u anyway for your answer :)

Comment: Consider this. If two clients are accepted, then for the second client the line `incoming = socket.Accept();` will overwrite the `incoming` from the first client. Similarly, `thrReceive` will be overwritten. Then later, when you call close/abort, you'll only be operating upon the last client, and the first client's socket/thread will still be alive.

Comment: ok this is true in the case I have two clients will connect to the server, but if i start the server without clients this way should work

Comment: @Francesco, consider creating your own Session class, and creating an instance of it for each client. In there you can store everything related to that client. That might make the model clearer.

Comment: I know that I'm boring you, but can u explain me how to do this? I'm really new on C#

Comment: I suppose your User class is similar to the Session class I'm talking about, so you already know how to do that. It's hard to see without seeing more of your code. You're asking quite a general question. Why don't you post back with more specific questions once you're a little further along.